# Parsing JSON, excpected

Tags: java, android

Im have problem. When parsing JSON, I get an error, why? Thanks for help !

```java
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

jsonString:

```json
{

  "power":{
    "battery_type"              : 4,
    "v_min_val"                 : 1340,
    "v_max_val"                 : 1460,
},
  "pwm":{
    "frequency"                 : 50,
},

}
```

```
Error: org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 133
```

Answer (score 1):

Values in JSON 'dictionaries' are separated by commas. However, in this input, you don't just separate by commas; you have a trailing comma and then nothing: `{"Foo": "Bar",}` is what you effectively have.

This is sensible and rather common style - after all, *without* that comma, adding another line would e.g. cause a version system commit to erroneously show the last line prior to the update to be updated (you didn't update it, you just added 1 comma at the end).

It's so sensible and common that a great many JSON parsers will allow these trailing commas and ignore them.

**It is not however JSON spec** - and thus there are also plenty of JSON parsers which straight up do not like this and will crash on such input, as is yours.

SOLUTION: Get a better JSON parser. Or ditch those trailing commas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I can't get rid of them, can you recommend some parser?

Comment: @adcmtomtom What blocks you from getting rid of them?